# Display a react-admin component based on the value of the record

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Maybe this is more of a general react question, as I'm not too familiar with it. But, I'm trying to get a component (edit button to start with) to be hidden depending on the value of the record (so, in a list view some records have edit buttons and some don't). I can't seem to get this to work with the `useRecordContext()` hook as described in the documentation.

The relevant parts of the code (with one of my attempts at making it work):

```
const AiohttpList = (resource, name, permissions, record) => (
    <List filters={createInputs(resource, name, "view", permissions)}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="show">
            {createFields(resource, name, permissions, true)}
            {hasPermission(`${name}.edit`, permissions, record) && <EditButton />}
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

function createResources(resources, permissions, record) {
    let components = [];
    for (const [name, r] of Object.entries(resources)) {
        components.push(<Resource
            name={name}
            create={hasPermission(`${name}.add`, permissions) ? AiohttpCreate(r, name, permissions) : null}
            edit={hasPermission(`${name}.edit`, permissions) ? AiohttpEdit(r, name, permissions) : null}
            list={hasPermission(`${name}.view`, permissions) ? AiohttpList(r, name, permissions, record) : null}
            show={hasPermission(`${name}.view`, permissions) ? AiohttpShow(r, name, permissions) : null}
        />);
    }
    return components;
}

const App = () => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    return (<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
        {permissions => createResources(STATE["resources"], permissions, record)}
    </Admin>);
};
```

I've also tried putting `useRecordContext()` in `AiohttpList` directly, but it always errors (maybe because of the for loop?). This version doesn't error, but `record` seems to be `undefined` and doesn't get called again when it actually fetches the records.

Comment: You were right initially by calling: const record = useRecordContext(); inside List and Datagrid, only there this call makes sense and yes, the cycle is not needed there.

Comment: Doing so just produces this error and nothing loads:
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<WithRecord render={(record: any) => hasPermission(`${name}.edit`, permissions, record) ? <EditButton /> : <></>} />
```

[WithRecord](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/WithRecord.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think I saw that element previously, but didn't understand how I'd use it in this context.